# Try implementing CKEditor in Remix js

Tags: ckeditor5, remix, mention

I am getting one error when I am implementing the CKEditor on Remix js using this NPM package
I am trying to implement the mention in CKEditor for remix js but getting an error

```
`import Editor from "ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor";
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import Mention from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention";`
```

Please find the error screenshot for your reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSBzX.png)
So if anybody knows about this error then please help me

I am try the mention NPM package to add a mention in CKEditor for remix js
NPM package is:

```
`import Mention from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention";`
```

and I want the custom mention in CKEditor for remix js

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue even without SSR. Can u just try deleting and re-installing the `node_modules`. This solved the issue for me.